# NPM CLI install/update single git dependency

Tags: node.js, git, npm, command-line-interface, package.json

I have a package.json with a lot of dependencies. It can look something like that (I omitted the other keys):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "git+ssh://git@github.com:arik-so/someRepository.git",
    "bs58check": "1.0.5",
    "canonical-json": "0.0.4",
    "compression": "1.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "1.3.1",
    "cookie-session": "^1.1.0",
    "csv": "0.4.2",
    "zpad": "0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Now, what I am trying to do is the following: I would like to use the CLI to only update the `body-parser` dependency. I am fine with reinstalling it, doing whatever needs to be done. I just do not want to have to do the full package installation because it takes too long. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between 'full package installation' and 'reinstalling'? By package, are you referring to your own package or the 'body-parser' package?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install --save 'git+ssh://git@github.com:arik-so/someRepository.git#master'` will install the latest version of this package